# DataLogging and NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, couchdb, bigdata, nosql

I have a Saas application that monitor equipments.

I developed a monitoring platform sensors.
My application currently oversees approximately `100,000` sensors.
A value is recorded every 15 minutes.

Each measurement is currently stored in a single MySQL table (timestamp => value).
To limit the number of rows in the `MySQL` table, all points of a single sensor are combined in a daily log.

The number of sensors increases exponentially.
My BDD is already `100GB`.

From these measures, I must make consolidations `daily, monthly, annual and total`.

My application needs to access recent data quickly, but I have to keep history for at least 10 years and can consult them.

`NoSQL architectures` seem to be the solution to store a lot of data and do the consolidation.

Which solution is most suitable for storing this type of data.

I tested `CouchDB`. I hesitate between different `NoSQL solution (Hadoop,cassandra, mongodb...)`

I'm looking for feedback on this experence.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give advice based on my experience with some of the technologies you mentioned.

**Use HDFS/Flume/Hadoop**

You might consider just writing plain text files and then using Flume (http://flume.apache.org/) to move them to HDFS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Hadoop_Distributed_File_System).

After that you can use Hadoop and all it's tool to write map/reduce jobs against the flat files that are stored in HDFS. HDFS will allow you to scale the storage size really well.

**Use Mongo**

You can set up a replica set in Mongo and scale horizontally to store log data, but 100GB and growing might be a bit too big for a replica set.  A replica set in Mongo (conceptually the same as a 'cluster') does *not* scale indefinitely.

If you found you were overloading a replica set you can shard the log information (maybe by sensor and id entry?) and then you can scale pretty much indefinitely by adding nodes.

-- I would find something that you enjoy writing queries in. Lots of solutions will scale horizontally, but not all have the same ecosystem around them.